# equation Ax=b, inside matrix form

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices, tikz-matrix

I am trying to write a matrix form of `Ax=b`, just by putting every letter inside a matrix. The output is as I want, but I need to make it more readable, by increasing the size of the `pmatrix` with every letter in the center !

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        A
    \end{pmatrix}
     \times
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        b
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could increase the size of the parentheses by inserting typographic struts inside the `\pmatrix` environments, as is done in the third and fourth equations in the following screenshot.

[image]

You didn't specify just how tall the `pmatrix`-parentheses should be, but I trust that the ones generated by including either `\tallstrut` or `\reallytallstrut` are sufficiently tall.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
% define two tall typographic struts:
\newcommand\tallstrut{\vphantom{\tfrac{(}{(}}}
\newcommand\reallytallstrut{\vphantom{\dfrac{A}{A}}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b} default (?) way of writing matrices and vectors
\qquad
    \begin{pmatrix} A \end{pmatrix} \times
    \begin{pmatrix} x \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix} b \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
    \begin{pmatrix} A\tallstrut \end{pmatrix} \times
    \begin{pmatrix} x\tallstrut \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix} b\tallstrut \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
    \begin{pmatrix} A\reallytallstrut \end{pmatrix} \times
    \begin{pmatrix} x\reallytallstrut \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix} b\reallytallstrut \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using `nicematrix` and the `Block` macro.

**MWE:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 1em]
    \Block{3-3}<\LARGE>{A}\\
     & & \\
     & &
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 1em]
    \Block{3-1}<\LARGE>{x}\\
    \ \\
    \ 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 1em]
    \Block{3-1}<\LARGE>{b}\\
    \ \\
    \ 
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image: The LaTeX output]